# Firebase Cloud Function never failing on 404 API call

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a function running on the creation of a document.

When I send this information to an external API Firebase returns on 'ok' message before the API call is complete.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const rp = require('request-promise');

const port = '****';
const ip = '***.***.***.***';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendUser = functions.firestore
  .document('user/{userId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const data = snap.data();
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      uri: 'http://' + ip + ':' + port + '/user',
      body: data,
      json: true,
    };

    rp(options)
      .then(function (parsedBody) {
        console.log('TEN ', parsedBody);
        return parsedBody;
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('ERR ', err);
        return err;
      });
  });
```

As you can see from my function it is not doing anything special apart from sending the data to an external source.

The API look like the following:-

```
app.post('/user', function (req, res) {

    fs.exists(path, function(exists) {
        if (exists === true) {
            console.log('Currently Printing Different User Info');
            fs.unlinkSync(path);        
            res.status(404).json({errorCode: 404, errorMessage: 'Currently Printing Different User.'});
            return;
        } else {
            fs.writeFile(path, '', () => { console.log('File Created'); });
            fs.unlinkSync(path);        
            res.status(200).json({statusCode: 200, statusMessage: 'Here we go'});
            return;
        }
    });
})
```

How can I get Firebase to recognise the returned 404 as a failed call, and also wait until the call is complete before returning ok or failed.

The API is behaving correctly with Postman but not when data is posted via Firebase.
Has anyone encountered this before, or can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

The data is being parse over to the serve but only once Firebase has returned with 'ok' even if I purposely trigger a fail.

I need this in place to be able to use the Firebase Cloud Function retry function.

Images can be seen @ https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN2Tj.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cloud Function returns the result before the call is complete because you don't return the Promise returned by the request-promise call.

Changing your code as follows should do the trick (at least for this problem):

```
exports.sendUser = functions.firestore
  .document('user/{userId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const data = snap.data();
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      uri: 'http://' + ip + ':' + port + '/user',
      body: data,
      json: true,
    };

    return rp(options) // <-- See the change here  
      .then(function (parsedBody) {
        console.log('TEN ', parsedBody);
        return parsedBody;
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('ERR ', err);
        return err;
      });
  });
```

I would suggest you watch the official Video Series (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) which explain very well this point about returning Promises for background functions (in particular the ones titled "Learn JavaScript Promises").

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that still returns 'ok' on a 404 response from the API. :-( This also returns 'Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value'

Comment: This has probably to do with the way you use/configure request-promise. You have probably to add `resolveWithFullResponse: true` in your options. See https://github.com/request/request-promise#get-the-full-response-instead-of-just-the-body.

Comment: For the second part of your comment (that you added later on): try returning `true` instead of `parsedBody`. Ideally you should return a Promise. For example if you write the response of the API to a document in the database you would return the Promise returned by `set()`.

Comment: I have tested with resolveWithFullResponse: true, and changed the returns to boolean but I get the following response https://imgur.com/a/UXv5pEZ

Comment: Where is hosted the API?

Comment: On which payment plan are you? The free "Spark" plan allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services. You may need to be on the "Flame" or "Blaze" plan if you API is not a Google-owned service. See  https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: On the image you provide we cannot see the entire error message.

Comment: I am hosting the API on an RPI, I am on the pay as you go blaze plan. Here is the full image https://imgur.com/a/0jP7uXa

Comment: As mentioned in the main thread, the API is receiving the correct data and sending back the response to Firebase, but it's not triggering a failed call.

Comment: If I am not mistaking, I think that it actually DOES trigger a failed call since the error message you show is generated by `console.log('ERR ', err);`, which is in the `catch()`.

Comment: It is the error from the catch, but when I have the Cloud retry function capability turned on, it doesn't retry the function, I need to trigger the retry function the only way it does that is if the function completely fails and is not just showing a console logged error. And the response error message is showing 20 seconds after firebase returns finished with status: 'ok'

Comment: Try returning `return false;` instead of `return err;`. There may be a delay for the console.log() to appear in the log, this is not an incorrect behavior.

Comment: I changed that earlier when I updates the then() to return true. Still no joy.

Comment: You could also try just with `return rp(options);` and no more `.then()` nor `catch()`. The Cloud Function will return the error generated by request-promise and will consider it as an error.

Comment: Same thing returns Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value. I have also tested returning a boolean on the API the the above return you mentioned. Am I trying to do something really outlandish?

Comment: No nothing really outlandish...  Are you testing locally or on the platform (after re-deploying)?

Comment: I have an Angular application running locally feeding data into the Cloud Firestore DB, which is then feeding into a API server locally in my house via my external IP. As previously mentioned the API is responding correctly and returning the correct errors but Firebase is not responding with an error.

Comment: Where is the Cloud function running? On the Firebase platform or locally (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator)?

Comment: The Firebase platform. Should we move this into private chat? Stackoverflow keeps warning me.

Comment: Actually I don't know how to help you more for the moment.... I would have to try your code in my testing environment (and set up an API to be called) and I have no more time today. I may give a try tomorrow afternoon (Brussels time)...

Comment: Ok thank you for your help, I am going to keep trying things my end. I can provide the code, or give you some form of access.